# alert message when login is false in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, alerts

I am new in node js trying to send Alert messages on screen iF user added the wrong credentials .Problem is , It through an error that Alert isn't defined .
if i send same message through res.send then it work without any error but I want to show alert
can someone guide me
Note : this code is written at server side file for node js
this code through an error say alerts is not defined

```
 Router.post('/login',(req,res)=>
 {

    const{
        email,
        password
    }=req.body;
    homeschema.findOne({email:email},(err,result)=>{
        if(email==result.email && password === result.password)
        {
            res.render('activate');

            
        }
        else
        {
            alert("incorrect email/password")
        }
    })
 })
```

this code is working fine and send a response message perfectly

```
 Router.post('/login',(req,res)=>
 {

    const{
        email,
        password
    }=req.body;
    homeschema.findOne({email:email},(err,result)=>{
        if(email==result.email && password === result.password)
        {
            res.render('activate');

            
        }
        else
        {
            res.send("EMAIL/PASSWORD incorrect");
        }
    })
 })
```

Comment: You know that saving a plain text password is an security issue?

Comment: What kind of behavior are you looking for here? Do you want like a `window.alert()` message on the frontend?

Comment: yes exactly i want to show email/password incorrect message on frontend

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is a backend framework and you cannot handle frontend alerts and popups here.
All you can do is handle alerts in the frontend based on the response you get from the backend(node.js server).
You can also make use of status codes so that it'll be easy for you to authenticate and do the next process.

Hope it helps!.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install a npm module for popups known as popups. You can install it using the command npm install popups. Then use it in the following way:

```
var popup = require('popups');

popup.alert({
    content: 'Hello!'
});
```